# Providing with data by using PHP exception mechanism

Tags: php, design-patterns, exception

Is it a good idea to provide with data some software components by using PHP exception mechanism. For instance:

```
class CFoo {
    function dispatchData($dataItem1, $dataItem2) {
        throw new CQuickTransport($dataItem1, $dataItem2);
    }
}


class CBar {
    function foo() {
        try {
            // Somewhere here throw our exception...
        }
        catch (CQuickTransport $e) {
            $dataItemArray = $e->getCargo();
            $dataItem1 = $dataItemArray[0];
            $dataItem2 = $dataItemArray[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to decide what benefit it is in the try - catch - Exception pattern that seems beneficial to your project, and emulate it with logic and objects.  Beyond the semantics that an exception is supposed to be exceptional, I would imagine that you will suffer a performance hit processing the try - catch.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions leave the normal flow of execution.  They are made for unintended results, hence the name "exception".  As a best practice they should only be used to catch and handled programming errors.